# How can i toggle state of two RadioButtons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the `Switch` component from `MUI` library. I want to achieve where only one `Switch` can be `checked` at a time. For instance, if `Switch A` is checked, when `Switch B` is checked, `Switch A` will be unchecked and vice versa. I am using the reducer pattern to achieve this.

Here is my code:

My reducer file:

```
// reducer.js

actionTypes = {
  toggle_price: 'toggle_price'
}

export const initialState = {
  fastprice: false,
  spotprice: true, 
}

export const toggleReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.toggle_price: {
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.event.target.name]: action.event.target.checked
      }
    }
  }
}

export const useToggler = ({ reducer = toggleReducer } = {}) => {
  const [{ fastprice, spotprice}, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)
 
  const togglePrice = (event) => dispatch({ type: 'toggle_price', event })

  return { togglePrice, fastprice, spotprice }
}
```

My component

```
//Component.js
const { togglePrice, spotprice, fastprice } = useToggler()

<FormControlLabel 
control={<Switch onChange={e => toggleButton(e)} checked={fastprice}  name='fastprice' />}label='Switch A' />

<FormControlLabel 
control={<Switch onChange={e => toggleButton(e)} checked={spotprice} name='spotprice' />}label='Switch B' />
```

This code checks both `Switch`components.

Comment: Can both switches be at the off state ?

Comment: No, one has to stay on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can hold the two radio buttons (or more) as a group to control the state of them.

for example combine the two radio button into one object and let just on radio button to be different.

try this solution.

```
const { togglePrice, radioGroup } = useToggler();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FormControlLabel
        control={
          <Switch
            onChange={(e) => togglePrice(e)}
            checked={radioGroup.fastprice}
            name="fastprice"
          />
        }
        label="Switch A"
      />

      <FormControlLabel
        control={
          <Switch
            onChange={(e) => togglePrice(e)}
            checked={radioGroup.spotprice}
            name="spotprice"
          />
        }
        label="Switch B"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const actionTypes = {
  toggle_price: "toggle_price"
};

export const initialState = {
  radioGroup: {
    fastprice: false,
    spotprice: true
  }
};

export const toggleReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.toggle_price: {
      const m = { ...state.radioGroup };
      for (let key in m) {
        m[key] = !action.event.target.checked;
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        radioGroup: {
          ...m,
          [action.event.target.name]: action.event.target.checked
        }
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const useToggler = ({ reducer = toggleReducer } = {}) => {
  const [{ radioGroup }, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const togglePrice = (event) => dispatch({ type: "toggle_price", event });

  return { togglePrice, radioGroup };
};
```

**live - DEMO**

https://codesandbox.io/embed/elastic-star-8o6e6i?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark